# Embedding dynamic resources to the android APK

Tags: android, python, gradle, android-studio

I would like to inject a few dynamic resources into the assets folder of the APK. Though I'm having no luck so far.

I was trying to inject some files to the APK as a zip archive using python script using `output.packageApplication.doLast`, but it doesn't add the files to the APK and generates the usual apk. I've checked whether it does anything with it and surprisingly it does, but it deletes the custom files and leaves only the compiled ones.

Can anybody shed some light?

Comment: Why would they have to be "dynamic", as opposed to being driven by a build type or product flavor?

Comment: I have flavors and sourceSets. The problem is that on gradle 1.1 this script worked just fine, but when I've migrated to gradle 2.2 it doesn't work as intended. The problem is that my script get Dex file from a library project and should inject it to the assets folder of the final APK. Also the script chooses the needed resources from the product flavors/sourceSets and injects it to the assets as well.